# Can't connect to internet with ASUS

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter

I have an ASUS x55la-hi31103j and I cannot connect to the internet after installing Windows 7.

I tried looking in the device manager to see what network adapter I have so I can download the drivers but it's not there?

I had already looked on the ASUS website, http://www.asus.com/us/Notebooks/X555LA/HelpDesk_Download/, but I could not find my laptop model.

Comment: The drivers will depend on your manufacturer and model of your computer.  Please add those details to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the information on your computer.  Please edit your question to include that information.  The answer you provided doesn't work.  The answer should be deleted.

Comment: I found the information I needed from one of your other posts on Stackexchange.  Welcome to the Stackexchange community.  If you specify important details in your questions, the support will come quicker.  You're get more input from more users, especially the ones who are familiar with the specifics such as hardware that you are using.  Hope the updated answer work!

Answer (score 2):

Please look at the Asus site http://www.asus.com/us/Notebooks/X555LA/HelpDesk_Download/ .  I didn't find the exact model number.  While browsing the site you may find other specifics and markings on your computer that will go to the more specific drivers page.

The specific driver page for your make and model will have drivers for all the peripherals including the sound, display, mouse and other components.

**Updated:**

The drivers for all the peripherals are at:

https://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/663/0/1/4O7N8NLQn6Lm0SuG/41/

Answer (score 0):

Like what @L. D. James said, find the drive on the Asus site: [List of Asus peripherals](https://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/663/0/1/4O7N8NLQn6Lm0SuG/41/)

Make sure you download from another computer & load it onto a flash drive or some other type of portable storage and then plug it into the Win 7 machine that can't connect and install the drivers.

Comment: Please tell me your exact computer model. I may be able to find a driver for you. I only need the computer at the moment. If I need the specs I will tell you.